# Why doesn't a string called by a function equal the string held in a command argument vector even though they ar the same

Tags: c

My code reads as below:
if (array[i].name == name)

Array.name is assigned by an argc, then name is entered by the user. I've used a debugger to check the values, and prior to hitting this if command, array[i].name = Joe and name = Joe.

But the if function doesn't run... I'm lost. Everything I can see is showing that these two strings hold the same word, so why won't the if command recognize that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to compare two strings, but that's not how you compare strings in C. You can use [strcmp()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) for example.

Comment: What you are comparing is memory addresses. You need a function to iterate through the strings and compare them char by char.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings in C like that.
As Paul Rooney said in the comment,

> You need a function to iterate through the strings and compare them
> char by char.

So you can either create your own function that iterates through the strings and compares them char by char or you can use [strcmp()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare the strings. Here's how to compare the strings using `strcmp()`:

```
if(strcmp(array[i].name,name)==0){
//do something if the strings are equal
}
```

Note:

> strcmp() returns an integer indicating the result of the comparison,
> as follows:
>
> • 0, if the s1 and s2 are equal;
>
> • a negative value if s1 is less than s2;
>
> • a positive value if s1 is greater than s2.